# Debian/kFreeBSD using ACLs on ZFS

Tags: debian, zfs, access-control-list

How can I use ACLs on a ZFS filesystem under Debian/kFreeBSD?

`uname -a`

`GNU/kFreeBSD foo1 8.2-1-amd64 #0 Thu Oct 27 20:48:27 UTC 2011 x86_64 amd64 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU X3220  @ 2.40GHz GNU/kFreeBSD`

I tried setfacl:

`setfacl -m user:root:rwx /Storage/TestFile1`

and it returns:

`setfacl: /Storage/TestFile1: Function not implemented`

I would like to use it as a fileserver, with samba.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZFS on Debian/kFreeBSD is still experimental and I guess ACL's are not (yet?) working.

Anyway, ZFS on this OS means you run a file system ported from another platform (Solaris) and put in a kernel that is then working in an alien runtime environment (Debian) considered experimental.  Doesn't sound like a good idea for a server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about debian's userspace (which I presume uses the GNU utilities), but according to [this guide](http://blogs.oracle.com/marks/entry/zfs_acls) it looks like ZFS ACL's are supposed to be set with `chmod` and read with `ls -v`:

```
chmod A+user:marks:delete:allow file.1
```

The info page for GNU chmod says that filesystem-specific attributes are normally set with a different command and suggests `chflags` or `chattr`, and `ls -v` is to "sort by version".

Comment: Unfortunatelly `chmod`, `ls -V` not working, because they are all GNU coreutils, which not support ACLs this way.